# Android samasung galaxy tab emulator resolut?

Tags: android, emulation, tablet

I have updated my  android sdk  with samsung galax tab addon , it installed successfully . problem is that when i open galaxy tab emulator, it displayed portion of emulator ,i.e; bottom of emulator is not visible. i thnk it is problem with desktop resolution , but resolution of desktop is 1280 X 1024 .  Can any one tell me how to get the display of galaxy tab emulator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Samsung has provided a Galaxy Tab Emulator below. It takes up a LOT of screen-space!

http://innovator.samsungmobile.com/galaxyTab.do

Comment: yeah it taking lot of screen space . how to reduce its resolution ?

Comment: You shouldn't reduce it's resolution as you won't be emulating the real thing if you do that. My suggestion is to get another monitor with a stand that allows you to view it vertically :-) ..Run the emulator on that.The other option would be to purchase the Tab of course, but that would be expensive!)

Comment: The link is no longer available.

Answer (score 3):

Galaxy tab has resolution of 600x1024. As its screen is as high as your screen (in pixels) it won't fit on your screen as the emulator borders also need some space.
You can scale the emulator when you launch it from AVD manager (instead by just running your app). Or you ran rotate it sideways as that way your display has enough pixels to display it. Rotate emulator by pressing ctrl + f12.

Answer (score 2):

Run the ADV manager, start the glaxay device. A screen will prompt, where you can "scale display to real size". Set a 7" screen (like in real life), and pretend your monitor screen is 50 DPI, you should have a reduced emulator.

Answer (score 1):

Those of you having trouble launching from Eclipse and not being able scale the display, use the following command line option (set via Run | Run Configurations):

```
-scale 0.57
```